# Javascript: how to make changes to the document before function finishes running?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to create a function that when called would display a "Loading..." message, and display the results as soon as it finishes. when I do it like this:

```
function load() {
    $('#status').html("loading...");

    /* do something */
    ...

    $('#status').html("done");
    $('results').html(result);
}
```

The "loading" message never appears, after a while what a user sees is just the "done" message and the results. How can I make the "loading" text appear just the moment I want it to?

Comment: btw how to add line breaks in code blocks? I couldn't figure it out xD

Comment: Click "edit" and you'll see how the question is formatted. If you add the line breaks *before* clicking on the code formatting button the line breaks are preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "do something" is synchronous, the browser never gets a chance to update the UI between the two content changes.

To have the changes appear you need to do something like:

```
$('#status').html('loading...');
setTimeout(function() {
     // do something

     $('#status').html('done');
}, 0);
```

The `setTimeout` call gives the UI a chance to update the display before jumping into your "something".

Note that if possible you should try to ensure that "something" *doesn't* tie up your browser for a long time.  Try to break the task up into multiple chunks, where each chunk is also dispatched using `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Is it the only way to give the UI chance to update? What if I call the setTimeout fnction without any parameters? will this update the ui?

Comment: AFAIK you have to use the callback - calling `setTimeout()` without parameters isn't sufficient to cause the UI to process all outstanding page updates.

Comment: @groovy354 page updates will only happen when the code block above has finished, but _then_ the callback is retrieved from the event queue and called (asynchronously)

Comment: So in order for the script to update the ui I have to nest every function in setTimeout? Is this the way it's done? xD Sorry... I always imagined it being a lot simplier

Comment: @groovy354  that's only necessary if you're forcing the browser to do something "continuous" between updates, i.e. blocking the event loop.  Any time the browser falls back into processing the event loop any outstanding updates will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing the "stuff" part, but I hope this helps a little;

```
function load() {
  $('#status').html("loading...");

  function onLoaded(result) {
    $('#status').html("done");
    $('results').html(result);
  }

  // do your stuff here

  // Not being able to see the "stuff", I guess you do some AJAX or something
  // else which is asynchronous? if you do, at the end of your callback, add
  // onLoaded(result)
}
```

Comment: if it was async he'd have a different problem - "done" appearing immediately.

Comment: In this example the "done" output can only occur after a call to onLoaded() has been made - is this example the one you're referring to please Alnitak?

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the "do something". It depends on what you want to do but I would expect that you want to use jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Many jQuery functions accept 'callback functions' which are executed after the task is complete. The callback function section of the load() documentation should explain everything.

Comment: Whatever it is that "//something" does (let it even be complicated array operations or benchmarking), how do I make the page content update accordingly to my code when I want it to? Why doesn't "$('#status').html("loading..."); " line take effect immediatly?